# How do I make my progressbar show the progess of a directory being copied

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a piece of code wich copies a folder to another directory. I wanted to implement a progress bar so the user can see the progress of the files being copied. I've tried some things, but I just cant get it to work.

This is the code I thought would do what I said above, but the progress bar doesn't make **any** progress, why the folder is actually being copied.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace intChanger
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        string Dirr;
        string Dirr2;
        int no = 0;
        int Count = 0;
        int Count2 = 0;
        private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
        {
            if (no == 0)
            {
                no = 1;
                Dirr = sourceDirName;
                Dirr2 = destDirName;
                Count = Directory.GetFiles(Dirr, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
                Count = 100 / Count;
            }

            // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                    "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
            }

            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
            // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
                Count2 = Count2 + 1;
                progressBar1.Value = Count2 * Count; 
            }

            // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
            if (copySubDirs)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                    DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryCopy(@"C:\Users\Stefan\Downloads\Portable Python 2.7.15 Basic (x64)\Portable Python 2.7.15 x64", @"C:\Users\Stefan\Documents\Backuppers_Backups\Portable Python 2.7.15 x64", true);
            MessageBox.Show("Done coppieng", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the Progress bar to go slowly up, but it doesn't: It stays at 0

However it does actually copy the files

Comment: I do not see any threads or Background workers?  Iooks like this all happening on the main thread...

Comment: Check whether the minimum and the maximum of the progress bar are set to 0 and 100

Comment: @User965207 the minimum and the maximum of the progress bar are indeed set to 0 and 100

Answer (score 3):

You should put the copy process in a [**BackgroundWorker**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) and refresh the progress bar from the *_bgwCopyOperation_ProgressChanged* event.
Because you are processing the copy operation in the GUI thread, you block controls from refreshing.

Try something like this. You still need to modify this a bit to pass the parameters to the *_bgwCopyOperation_DoWork* event.

```
private void _bgwCopyOperation_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (no == 0)
    {
        no = 1;
        Dirr = sourceDirName;
        Dirr2 = destDirName;
        Count = Directory.GetFiles(Dirr, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        Count = 100 / Count;
    }    

    // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
        + sourceDirName);
    }    

    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
    // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        Count2 = Count2 + 1;

        //Update progressbar here
        _bgwCopyOperation.ReportProgress(Count2 * Count);
    }

    // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}


private void _bgwCopyOperation_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: I looked into it, but I struggled upon another issue: In `_bgwCopyOperation_DoWork` is `DirectoryCopy` called. But because you made it a BackgroundWorker, DirectoryCopy doesn't exist anymore. How do I call that function form inside the BackgroundWorker?

Comment: That's how Background workers work. It was not just a rename of your function. My answer was just an approach for you. Read the link in my answer. Start the Backgroundworker with something like 
 _bgwCopyOperation.RunWorkerAsync(parameters)

Comment: So I changed `DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
` with `_bgwCopyOperation.RunWorkerAsync(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);` but now it gives me the following error: `No overload for method 'RunWorkerAsync' takes 3 arguments`

Comment: You must wrap your multiple parameters into one. For example as an array or own class/struct. RunWorkerAsync (object argument) <--One parameter

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/4652fe02 that is my code now, but now it doesn't change the progress bar and doesn't copy the folder

Comment: You still have a invalid signature of _bgwCopyOperation_DoWork. This method must have the following signature *(object sender,  DoWorkEventArgs e)* ALL parameters have to be in ***e***

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SasHPaxW that is my code now, It does copy the files now, but It still doesn't change the progress bar. I found 1 thing that if I try `Progressbar1.refresh()` it gives me the error that the progress bar was created on another thread (I commented where that was)

Comment: It is absolutely correct to get the error when calling .Refresh(). You should check the calculations of your percentage calculation and the used datatypes. An integer is not suitable for your calculation. But this is a different subject.

Comment: May I ask why this is off topic, the subject off this whole question is how to make the progress bar move correctly right?

Comment: Making the bar move is something different than calculating the value. What value is *Count2 * Count*?

Answer (score 0):

The BackgroundWorker is certainly the best approach, it will send all the heavy copy into a separate thread an not keep the GUI thread busy with simple copy.

...but if you are copying small folders, you could try using the `Refresh` function on the progress bar:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProgressBat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = i;
                progressBar1.Refresh();
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

That example will get the progress bar moving correctly.
And it is a one line fix to your code